# How can an MSI prompt the user for parameters to configure an MSM?

Tags: parameters, windows-installer, merge-module

I have an application *BACK* which is packaged in an Merge Module, and installed with another application *FRONT* which is in the main MSI package.  These are created via projects in MS VisStudio 2008.

The user can configure the *FRONT* application through the MSI's UI with a small set of parameters.  I need to access at least one of these parameters (in this case a URL) so that at runtime *BACK* can access *FRONT*.

- In MS Visual Studio, I can't view a UI for the MSM project to prompt the user.
- Parameters set in the MSI's UI are apparently not passed through to the MSM -- a class 
  in the MSM (derived from *System.Configuration.Install.Installer*) is used, but its
  *Install* function is called w/an empty *IDictionary*.

I've searched Google, MSDN, SO and others but haven't even found anyone (using VisStudio) with this question. MSDN seems to have a lot of info on abstractions, with no reference to any tool, it leaves me to think it's intended for developers of install *tools* rather than of install packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [installer properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372432%28VS.85%29.aspx) for this. A MSI can access a MSM property by using this syntax:

```
<property name>.<module GUID>
```

So if you use a custom property in your MSM, for example MY_URL, you can set it from your MSI by using:

```
MY_URL.{B5C20B75-2B3F-4323-9584-C426E8AEE3BF}
```

where "{B5C20B75-2B3F-4323-9584-C426E8AEE3BF}" represents the merge module GUID.

Comment: I no longer work with MSWindows, so _I_ don't care, but thanks anyway might help the next person....